test if any object refer to by a base model has a value specified in django orm
Well consider two models:
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default="hello world")

class Student(models.Model):
    key = models.TextField(default="somedata")
    a = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)

So a many to one relationship from School to Student
How would I get (from School's perspective) all School which have a Student that set "key" to the required value?
Especially in the already existing query:
School.objects.filter(Q(name="hello world") | Q(queryshould_here))

I've tried
A.objects.filter(Q(name="hello world") | Q(student__key="test"))

However that (obviously) fails with:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'key' for ManyToOneRel or join on the field not permitted.


both models have tables in the same database?

@willeM_VanOnsem yes of course.

The query:
School.objects.filter(Q(name='hello world') | Q(student__key='test'))
should work, given you did not specify a related_quey_name=… [Django-doc] or related_name=… [Django-doc]. If you did, Django will pick the related_query_name=…, and if you did not specify that, the related_name=….
But the error:

Unsupported lookup 'v' for ManyToOneRel or join on the field not permitted.

says you thus seem to use a __v, so probably the lookup is where it goes wrong, or you make wrong JOIN.

See my comment about "v". But in the production code specifying the related_name is kind of hard: as the foreign key is specified on a generic (abstract) student class.

@paul23: is it possible to edit the question with the inheritance and abstract model base class. Obfuscating is not a problem, but I think with the obfuscation you are (unintentionally) hiding the issue why it does not work.
